# What is the best 2D driver for GeForce4 MX 440?

Tags: nvidia, 2d

I still haven't upgraded to the latest version of ubuntu because of poor support for this video card. What is the recommended upgrade path to ensure maximum 2D performance?

Answer (score 2):

What is the driver that you are use? by "Hardware Driver"? If you use the "Hardware Drier" to download the driver, you might want to try using the open source driver, take a look on this: http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux_display_x86_96.43.11.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running 10.10 via live CD to check performance?

I found [this OMG Ubuntu post](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/nvidia-96-driver-ubuntu-10-10-fix/) about fixing the Nvidia driver in 10.10 that may help if the default one is giving you issues, it also links to a Ubuntu Forums post but some of the comments on OMG may be useful.